# Efficient JPA query to find if at least one record exists with given condition

Tags: java, jpa, orm

Given following JPA queries to find if there is **at least** one record with given condition, which one is more efficient (performance)?

A)

```
boolean notFound = entityManager
       .createQuery("SELECT f.id FROM Foo f WHERE f.active = true")
       .setMaxResults(1)
       .getResultList()
       .isEmpty();
```

B)

```
boolean notFound = entityManager
     .createQuery("SELECT COUNT(f.id) FROM Foo f WHERE f.active = true")
     .getSingleResult() == 0
```

Comment: in B you have to cast to `long` or `int` before use `== 0`, no?

Comment: Using a `@NamedQuery` might beat those two solutions.

Comment: @AlexandroSifuentesDíaz true, I just wanted to keep it more readable here

Comment: @Tunaki you can assume both of them are defined as named query.

Comment: _Performance and JPA?_ does not make sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have more than a trivial amount of Foo records, your DB supports something like a LIMIT clause, and the JPA impl is clever enough to use it, and DB recognizes it as equivalent to a EXISTS query, then option 1 should outperform option 2.

Here is a nice [explanation](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2007/12/15/exists-vs-count-the-battle-never-ends.aspx).